# Why model's loss is always revolving around 1 in every epoch?

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, tf.keras

During training, loss of my model is revolving around "1". It is not converging.
I tried various optimizer but it still showing the same pattern. I am using keras with tensorflow backend. What could be possible reasons? Any help or reference link will be appreciable.

[image]
here is my model:

```
def model_vgg19():
  vgg_model = VGG19(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(128,128,3))

  for layer in vgg_model.layers[:10]:
    layer.trainable = False

  intermediate_layer_outputs = get_layers_output_by_name(vgg_model, ["block1_pool", "block2_pool", "block3_pool", "block4_pool"])
  convnet_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(vgg_model.output)
  for layer_name, output in intermediate_layer_outputs.items():
    output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(output)
    convnet_output = concatenate([convnet_output, output])

  convnet_output = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(convnet_output)
  convnet_output = Dropout(0.6)(convnet_output)
  convnet_output = Dense(2048, activation='relu')(convnet_output)
  convnet_output = Lambda(lambda  x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1)(convnet_output)

  final_model = Model(inputs=[vgg_model.input], outputs=convnet_output)

  return final_model


model=model_vgg19()
```

here is my loss function:

```
def hinge_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, _EPSILON, 1.0-_EPSILON)
    loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(0,dtype=tf.float32)
    g = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)

    for i in range(0, batch_size, 3):
        try:
            q_embedding = y_pred[i+0]
            p_embedding = y_pred[i+1]
            n_embedding = y_pred[i+2]
            D_q_p =  K.sqrt(K.sum((q_embedding - p_embedding)**2))
            D_q_n = K.sqrt(K.sum((q_embedding - n_embedding)**2))
            loss = (loss + g + D_q_p - D_q_n)            
        except:
            continue
    loss = loss/(batch_size/3)
    zero = tf.constant(0.0, shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.maximum(loss,zero)
```

Comment: To answer this question, more information is needed from your side. What are the inputs to your hinge_loss? Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @Koanashi just edited the question. FYI I am working on street2shop problem and the inputs are the triplets(anchor, positive and negative images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is definitely a problem is that you shuffle your data and then try to learn triplets out of this.

As you can see here: https://keras.io/models/model/ model.fit shuffles your data in each epoch, making your triplet setup obsolete. Try to set the shuffle parameter to false and see what happens, there might be different errors as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After setting the shuffle to false its working. I got the answer. I have upvoted. Initially it was converging but after 20 to 30th epoch the loss is not converging, its rounding around 0.72 to 0.65, what possible reasons could be there. As you can see I am using momentum to the highest i.e 0.9 and learning rate is moderate.

Comment: Maybe try an Adam Optimizer. Without having access to the data it is hard to tell, but Adam tends to give good results regardless of what you do, just not the best results.